# Drawing to Canvas in Android throws Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to create a simple render of a background with an image on top to update roughly every 30seconds. I am using a canvas to get this done but when I try and print to the canvas it throws a NPE. As far as I can tell the canvas has been initialised. The activity starts the view which starts/stops the thread that runs the draw method. It is in the draw method that the NPE is thrown. This is the activity that starts it all:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    view = new GameView(this);
    setContentView(view);
    view.onCreate();
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    view.onPause();
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    view.onResume();
}
```

These are the main functions of my Surface View:

```
public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setFocusable(true);
}

public void onCreate() {
    _drawThread = new DrawThread(getHolder(), this);
}

synchronized public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.getHeight(); //returns NPE
}

public void onResume() {
    if (!_drawThread.isAlive()) {
        _drawThread.setRunning(true);
        _drawThread.start();
    } else {
        _drawThread.setRunning(true);
    }
}

public void onPause() {
    boolean retry = true;
    _drawThread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) {
        try {
            _drawThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

And my draw thread looks like:

```
public void run() {
    Canvas c;
    while (_running) {
        c = null;
        try {
            c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                _game.draw(c);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
            _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From what I can tell the canvas somehow doesn't get initialised before the draw thread is created which causes the NPE but I can't see what is wrong with the code. A little help or advise would be great.

Comment: the canvas must be null, what is _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas() returning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your own `SurfaceHolder.Callback` or `SurfaceHolder.Callback2` with the `SurfaceHolder` and ensure the surface has been created before attempting to draw into it.  If you attempt to lock the canvas before the surface has been created, it will not be able to give you a `Canvas` object.  You usually don't need to override `SurfaceView`, but just use it as a mechanism to get access to the backing surface in which you wish to draw.

Comment: I have the thread set to start onResume() of the View and stop onPause() however onResume() doesn't occur until after the surface has been created. How do I prevent the thread drawing if the app is paused but don't startup until the surface view has been recreated?

Comment: OK so I set thread to start once the surface has been created and end once the surface has been destroyed. However the thread is still running when the canvas is destroyed. This results in a NPE on exiting the activity.

Comment: I'm confused by your last comment.  If you are stopping the thread once the surface is destroyed, why is the thread still running?  You're on the right track - you have to manage when something is drawn to the surface by being both surface aware and lifecycle aware.